# subir archivos a dropbox con PHP - dropbox SDK

Tags: php

Estoy intentado subir archivos con php utilizando la liberia [dropbox-sdk-php](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php)

Este es el código que estoy utilizando

```html
$dropboxKey ='MY_KEY';
$dropboxSecret ='MY_SECRET';
$appName='MY_APPNAME';
$acessToken = "MY_ACCESTOKEN";

$appInfo = new Dropbox\AppInfo($dropboxKey,$dropboxSecret);
//Store CSRF token
$csrfTokenStore = new Dropbox\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION['k6'],'dropbox-auth');
//define auth details
$webAuth = new Dropbox\WebAuth($appInfo,$appName,'http://localhost',$csrfTokenStore);
$client = new Dropbox\client($acessToken,$appName,'UTF-8');

//time to upload file
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
        $ext = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']); 
        $ext =end($ext);           
        $fullname = "/". $nombre .'.'.$ext; 
        $size = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['size']); 
  try{
           
        $client->uploadFile($fullname,Dropbox\WriteMode::add(),$tempFile,$size);
  
  }catch(Dropbox\Exception_InvalidAccessToken $e){
       Echo "Error";
  }

}
```

no me muestra ningun error pero el post me devuelve codigo de estado: 500

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el problema con la ayuda de stackiverflow en ingles 
dejo el enlace al post

[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445545/upload-files-to-dropbox-with-php-dropbox-sdk-php)

La solicion era cambiar el SDK ya que la api de Dropbox no era compatible con la librería